# scanf with 'E' skip my whole loop once

Tags: c, scanf

Sorry If this question is bad , but I cannot figure this out

Program concept: It reads 1 input per line until * is present as input N means North S mean south  NE means northeast etc... and find your location in x,y after reaching *

Input Format Example: 8N means move north 8 unit

PROBLEM!!: When I enter text as 8N,8W,8S,8NE.... It just work fine and display "blablabla" as in my loop. But when I enter text as 1E,2E,3E No "blablabla" is present and my x is not increased or decreased. Is this because of scanf?

Thank you for all help

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char temp[3];
    double x=0,y=0,tt;
    while(temp[1]!='*')
    {
        temp[2]=0;
        temp[1]='E';
        scanf("%lf",&tt);
        scanf("%s",&temp[1]);
        printf("blablabla");
        if(temp[1]=='E'&&temp[2]==0)
        {
            x+=tt;
        }
        if(temp[1]=='N'&&temp[2]==0)
        {
            y+=tt;
        }
        if(temp[1]=='W'&&temp[2]==0)
        {
            x-=tt;
        }
        if(temp[1]=='S'&&temp[2]==0)
        {
            y-=tt;
        }
        tt/=1.41421356237;
        if(temp[1]=='N'&&temp[2]=='E')
        {   
            x+=tt;
            y+=tt;
        }
        if(temp[1]=='N'&&temp[2]=='W')
        {
            x-=tt;
            y+=tt;
        }
        if(temp[1]=='S'&&temp[2]=='E')
        {
            x+=tt;
            y-=tt;
        }
        if(temp[1]=='S'&&temp[2]=='W')
        {
            x-=tt;
            y-=tt;
        }
    }
    printf("%.3lf %.3lf\n",x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have input like this: `1E`, the `E` is consumed in the attempt to read a floating-point number, like for example `1E+00`. The subsequent `scanf("%s")` then tries to read the whole next input as string, so when your input is `1E 2E`, `tt` is 1.0 and the string is `2E`.

You can find out such strings ba printing out the values of the variables instead of just a placeholder like "blabla".

That said: Your string `temp` is very short. You can legally enter at most two characters, because one char needs to be reserved for the terminating null char. You are overflowing your buffer and probably corrupt other data.

Make your char array bigger and provide a maximum buffer length to prevent overflow:

```
char temp[20];

scanf("%19s", temp);      // Allow at most 19 chars
```

In the code above, I've just passed the array, not a pointer to its second element. You should do that, too, and make all your array indexes zero-based, as is customary in C:

```
if (temp[0] == 'N' && temp[1] == 'E') ...
```

**Edit**: It appears that the `strtod` function does not show the same behaviour as `scanf("%lf")`, at least not in the (few) implementations I tried. Here's an attempt to read input of the form float, string, where both must not be separated by white space:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[40];

    while(scanf("%39s", buf) == 1 && *buf != '*')
    {
        double dist;
        char *dir;

        dist = strtod(buf, &dir);

        if (dist == 0 && dir == buf) {
            printf("Invalid input\n");
            continue;
        }

        printf("%g '%s'\n", dist, dir);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This seems to work. If `strtod` goes past the `E` despite the missing exponent in an implementation, you can always trace `dir` one back in this solution that works with temporary strings.

Comment: Sir, in general, you're very true, but is that the case here ? [i mean `char` wise comparison ]

Comment: @SouravGhosh: You mean that buffer overflow is not the actual cause of the error? I could not reproduce the OP's behaviour as described, but a three-char array that is effectively shortened to a two-char one seems a likely contender for unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Oh, of course: The `E` is being treated as exponent!

Comment: Because `23N`, `1W` and so cannot be valid floating-point numbers. The problem is that there is no exponent after the `E`, but the scanner doesn't track back. (My cygwin implementation recognises `1E` as you'd expect, the Visual Studio Lib doesn't. Not that it is legal to scan over the `E`.)